# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write_pdf'

Tags: python, python-3.7

I started studying machine learning. I am following a google tutorial, but I face this error and the answers that I have found haven't work in my code. I'm not sure but it seems that the Python version has changed and doesn't use some library anymore.

This is the error:

```
[0 1 2]
[0 1 2]

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Moi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\six.py", line 31
    "(https://pypi.org/project/six/).", DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: The module is deprecated in version 0.21 and will be removed in version 0.23 since we've dropped support for Python 2.7. Please rely on the official version of six (https://pypi.org/project/six/).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Moi\Desktop\python\ML\decision tree.py", line 30, in <module>
    graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write_pdf'
```

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris ()
test_idx = [0,50,100]

#training data
train_target = np.delete(iris.target ,test_idx)
train_data = np.delete(iris.data, test_idx, axis= 0)

#testing data
test_target = iris.target [test_idx]
test_data = iris.data[test_idx]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier ()
clf.fit (train_data, train_target)
print (test_target )
print (clf.predict (test_data))
# viz code
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydot
dot_data =StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf,
        out_file=dot_data,
        feature_names=iris.feature_names,
        class_names=iris.target_names,
        filled= True, rounded=True,
        impurity=False)
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

Comment: The version issue has nothing to do with the error, it just warns you that in the future you won't be able to use `sklearn.externals.six`. The error is because `graph` is a python list who cannot be directly exported to pdf (also that is probably not what you want), it would really help if you linked the tutorials you are following so we can see what are those trying to do.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKxRvEZd3Mw&list=PLT6elRN3Aer7ncFlaCz8Zz-4B5cnsrOMt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`graph_from_dot_data` returns a tuple, you have to explode it to get to the graph.

Change:

```
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

to:

```
(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

Credit: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/84621/pydot.graph_from_dot_data

Comment: TypeError: 'Dot' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @ChediHarabi that's a new issue, please post it separately (as a new question) with all the relevant information: code, which line throws the error, stacktrace if available and etc